# display row data as column title in a CTE

Tags: sql-server

in SQL Server 2014 i have  table that contain student absence information, i make a CTE from that table to display **StudentName**,**CName** as column title and the absence hours for each student in each course.
this is my CTE code:

```
DECLARE @SummaryTable TABLE
(
  SName nvarchar(50),-- Student Name
  CName nvarchar(50) -- Course Name
 )
    INSERT INTO @SummaryTable(SName, CName)
    SELECT Student_tbl.SName,Sum_Abs from Absence_Summary_tbl
    inner join Student_tbl on Student_tbl.S_ID = Absence_Summary_tbl.S_ID
    inner join Stages_tbl on Stages_tbl.Stage_ID = Student_tbl.Stage_ID
    where Stages_tbl.Stage_ID = 1;
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT SName, CName,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SName ORDER BY CName) AS rn FROM @SummaryTable )
SELECT SName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN CName ELSE 0 END) AS CName1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN CName ELSE 0 END) AS CName2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN CName ELSE 0 END) AS CName3
FROM CTE
GROUP BY SName;
```

The result of CTE is display like image below:

[image]

in the result it display Course names as CName1,CName2,CName3 as column titles, is there any way to display real course names except the aliases as column titles for course names. in my real table '**Absence_Summary_tbl**' i have a Course Name in a column called **CName**.

Comment: Can you provide output result and input data? The image which you mentioned does not have any data..

Comment: your sample query shows CName is not storing the course name rather sum_abs. Insert [SName, CName, Sum_Abs] in your table variable.

Answer (score 0):

In @SummaryTable you are inserting the sum_Abs instead of CourseName,
@SummaryTable should have 3 columns SName, CName, Sum_Abs(to store the absent count per student per course)

there is no need of CTE to achieve this 
Use Pivot instead:-

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CName) 
                    from Absence_Summary_tbl
                    group by CName
                    order by CName
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT SName,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select SName, CName, Sum_Abs
                from @SummaryTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Sum_Abs)
                for CName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, when i run you code it gives me an error 'Must declare the table variable "SummaryTable"', is your pivot also need SummaryTable or what is this error?

Comment: Yes You have to Declare the Table Variable as below:-                                      DECLARE @SummaryTable TABLE
(
  SName nvarchar(50),-- Student Name
  CName nvarchar(50), -- Course Name
  Sum_Abs int -- absent count per student per course
 )